# X-Editable. Glitches with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox, x-editable

I've already asked question about checkboxes which changed their state by main checkbox and got complete answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29476416/x-editable-turn-off-on-checkboxes-via-main-checkbox-in-edit-mode).
It was my fault that I didn't clearly and fully formulated my question because I also need to disable turned off checkboxes. I simply edited provided answer and it seems to be ok.

```
   $(document).on('click', 'input[name=maincb]', function ()
    {
        var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
        $(document).find('.sup.editable-input').each(function ()
        {

            if ($(this).is(':checked') != checked)
            {
                $(this).trigger('click');
                $(this).attr("disabled", !checked);
            }
        });
    });
```

But... There are following glitches:

1)When I several time tries to select/deselect all checkboxes it works on odd attempts -- in edit mode deselect all and then select all... ops no checkboxes are in select state, they were enabled yes, but not selected. I guess it is something with event propagation...

2)When all selected and I switch off, say second checkbox, now it is switched off and then I deselect them all then this second cb is not disabled as it should be. Why?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/7544/) is here.

So, main question how to cope with these glitches?

And the last but not least question -- is it possible to cope with this job only with x-editable/angularjs functionality without jquery?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you should attach ng-model to checkboxes, not changing checkbox values yourself.

Comment: Hi. And what ng-model should be assigned to?

Comment: I understand your situation now, but i think it will be hard to do. because xeditable copy your checkbox values (sup[0], sup[1], sup[2]) into $data in each of their scopes and you want to reflect those before xeditable apply data base to scope.